# LoaderManager is being called automatically on pressing Back key in Android?

Tags: java, android, loader, android-loadermanager

I am newbie in Android. Here is the LoaderManager class I have written code on Button click to initialize Loader. When I am pressing back button of device I came to previous activity and my call to Initialize loader is again called and it automatically starts new activity without pressing any key even my initialize loader is on button click.

Why is it happening so?

**LoginActivityService.java**

```
     public class LoginActivityService extends Activity implements
                LoaderCallbacks<User> 
         {Context context;
              @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.login_view_service);
                context = this;
                userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName1);
                password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
                loginBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login1);
                logoutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout1);
                loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        doLogin(userName.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
                    }
                });
            }
      public void doLogin(String userNameString, String passwordString) {
            Log.i("do login button if", "login button clicked" + "username:"
                    + userNameString + "passwor:" + passwordString);
            if (userNameString.length() == 0 || passwordString.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "UserName Or Password Should be Filled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
      else
    { try {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null,LoginActivityService.this);
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("do Login Stack Trace if Response false","do Login Stack Trace Catch Block");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }}
   @Override
    public Loader<User> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
Log.i("in loader", "login button clicked" + "username:"+ userName.getText().toString() + "passwor:"
                + password.getText().toString());
        loginLoader = new LoginLoader(context, userName.getText().toString(),
                password.getText().toString(), "2013-07-10 01:18:26");
        Log.i("login loader", "" + loginLoader);
        return loginLoader;
}
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<User> arg0, User userInstance) {
             Log.i("status", "" + userInstance);
 if (userInstance == null) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User Id and Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityService.this,
                    ProposalListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
}
@Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<User> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // getLoaderManager().restartLoader(10000,null,LoginActivityService.this);
    }
}
```

My problem is I am getting data from Service and "userInstance" is not null so it moves towards nextActivity but when I press back key of device it comes to the previous activity and it automatically moves to the same activity from where we have pressed back key. This is happening because my class that extends AsyncTaskLoader have onloadinBackground() and this method is being called again can someone point me why this is happening:

```
     public class LoginLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<User>
     {
   @Override
    public User loadInBackground() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        User listUser = LoginListService.getLoginInstance().getLoginResult(userName,password,apkVersion);
        Log.d(TAG, "load in background");
        return listUser;
    }
     }
```

Can someone please guide me what code I need to add in this to avoid automatic call of loadinBackground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to destroy the loader once you received data:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<User> arg0, User userInstance) {
    Log.i("status", "" + userInstance);
    if (userInstance == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User Id and Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(arg0.getId());
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityService.this,
            ProposalListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: and when i am recieving false data from server and trying to resend correct information to server so its not accepting correct information and giving the same response "false"  in short after first false response my initloader is not being called with correct values

Comment: I am not following you ... All I am suggesting is once you received the data from server, you don't need to restart the loader.

Comment: ok i have done same as what u told but in absence of internet my app is failed to bring data from webservice and it crashed how can i handle this part if internet not present then atleast it should show UI with null data

Comment: The app is crashing because of the loader? Or because you're not handling lack of internet data? You could return a `User` object and have in there a `success/fail` flag and handle that.

Comment: can u let me know one thing ....i am using list and that list is recieving data from loader class and loader is setting data to adapter and moreover my list is being filled but when internet connection disabled so my loader did not bring data and as well as onLoadFinished never called and it throws NPE error .Whats the way to show list with dialog that no network connection and list remains empty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46334/discussion-between-user3233280-and-gunar)

Comment: Simply create a wrapper class that contains your expected data and two more: a boolean that signals success download and a String, fail reason. When you're making the request construct this wrapper object. If the response is successful set the data to what you received and the flag to true. If request failed, set the flag to false and the fail message to something meaningful. In `onLoadFinished` you would check first what is the value of the flag and then decide: get the data and show it or show the fail message. Makes sense?